# Angular UI-Grid doesn't take 100% width when div's width is changed

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I initially have 2 div's side by side and I am trying to hide a div and making the other div take up the entire width.

The div has a UI Grid and it is taking up the entire div but the columns don't get autosized.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $timeout(function () {
                $scope.gridApi.core.handleWindowResize();

            }, 50);
            $scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
```

This did the job